# NodeJS ( HapiJS ) Parsing XML

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, soap, hapi.js

I'm new in parsing and XML and using nodejs, I have try `node-soap`, `easysoap`, `strong-soap`, but I can't make neither that library work

this is my xml if I open the link the browser

```
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:myserv" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:myserv">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:myserv">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>

            <xsd:complexType name="reqSearch">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Username" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="respSearch">...</xsd:complexType>

        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="SearchRequest">
        <part name="param" type="tns:reqSearch"/>
    </message>
    <message name="SearchResponse">
        <part name="return" type="tns:respSearch"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="searchPortType">
        <operation name="Search">
            <documentation>Search Service</documentation>
            <input message="tns:SearchRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:SearchResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="searchBinding" type="tns:searchPortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="Search">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:s-service#Search" style="rpc"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:s-service" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:s-service" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="myserv">
        <port name="searchPort" binding="tns:searchBinding">...</port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

What I try till now is like this

```
var clientParams = {
           host    : 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
           path    : '/xxxxx/xxxx.php',
           wsdl    : '/xxxxxxx/xxxx.php?wsdl'
        };

        var clientOptions = {
            secure : false 
        };

        var soapClient = easysoap.createClient(clientParams, clientOptions);   
        soapClient.call({
        method    : "Search",
        params: {
            Username: "test",
        }
    })
    .then((callResponse) => {
        console.log(callResponse.data); // response data as json
        console.log(callResponse.body); // response body
        console.log(callResponse.header);  //response header
    })
    .catch((err) => { throw new Error(err); });
```

but there is no result. I think what I code is wrong. Please guide me how to parsing XML and get the result of `respSearch`

Comment: Do you receive any errors in your `console.log("Got an error making SOAP call: ", err);` block?

Comment: @DavidR I already update my code, I put a wrong code in there. What I got is not error but callResponse.data from my console.log. The result is `{ Fault: 
[ { faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Client' },
{ faultactor: '' },
{ faultstring: 'error in msg parsing:\nXML error parsing SOAP payload on line 34: Attribute redefined' },
{ detail: '' } ] }`

Comment: If your response is having whitespaces at the top, you may get into this error, Can you please try the `trim` function like this, `console.log(callResponse.data.trim());`

Comment: @DavidR I can't do a trim, the error said `You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection: Error: TypeError: callResponse.data.trim is not a function`